# Request.QueryString usage to read Passed array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm not able to read the array passed from the other page with Request.Querystring

```
//Label1.Text += FID[l]; //Checked the array and it is printing properly.

Response.Redirect("show.aspx?id=" + ID + "&name=" + NAME + "&fileid=" 
                  +FID+"&length="+j);


string fid=string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["fileid"].ToString())))
{
    fid = Request.QueryString["fileid"].ToString();

}

for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
{

    Label1.Text += fid[l]; //Printing wrong array
}
```

Can anybody help me with this.

How can I use **Global.aspx** file to do this instead of parameter passing.

Comment: what is the value of fid before the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense, first of all If that code is all in the same method then nothing after the Response.Redirect will run.

Second assuming the Response.Redirect is not in the same method as the other code then

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["fileid"].ToString())))
```

On the above line you are calling ToString() on something that is already a string and then converting it to a string. If Request.QueryString["fileid"] is null then this will throw a null reference exception. You should do:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["fileid"]))
```

Third fid is a string, Label1.Text is a string.  Why are you looping through the string char by char and then adding them onto the end Label1.Text.

Finally fid will contain whatever is passed as the query string param "fileid", it can't contain anything else.  If it has the "wrong" value then the "wrong" value is getting passed in the query string.

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass a array in Response.Redirect.

Comment: You can't pass an array into a query string as such but providing it is an array of strings you could do `string MyString = string.Join(",",MyArray);` to turn it into a single string with the each element seperated by a comma.  You can then turn it back into an array at the other end with something like `string[] MyArray = MyString.Split(',');`

Comment: Why don't u add the above comment to ur answer I will mark it as right answer.